# Does vim's expression register support powers of numbers?

Tags: vim

I want to calculate 2^11 in vim but it says that this is an invalid expression, so I began wondering if this is even a feature

Comment: [`pow(2, 11)`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim 7.2 introduced support for floating-point numbers, and added some related functions. `pow()` is among them:

```
:echo pow(2, 11)
```

If you need an Integer value / don't want the appended `.0`, wrap this in `float2nr()`.